How can I insulate cables using a copper braid too thin to sheathe them?
I have high-voltage SHV cables that I need to shield using a copper braid. I am using sensitive electronics and these cables appear to be a source of noise.
The only copper braid that I have available, unfortunately, is too thin for the cables. It is flat (not a sheath), 4 mm wide. My cables are approximately 5 mm in diameter, and the connectors 15 mm in diameter. I cannot order another braid right now, and I have to make do with this braid.
Can I use it to coat the cables somehow? I was thinking of maybe coiling the braid around them like a spring or something like this.

This sounds bad! SHV is coax cable, so all relevant field should be between outer and inner conductor of your coax, and none outside – unless you're using the SHV coax out of spec, or you have common mode problems in your system. In both cases, you'd need to solve the issue at the source, not at the cable.

Please explain why you need to shield the cable

@MarcusMüller Thank you very much for your answes. Well, I am working on high-sensitivity electronics and recently, I have had issues with a large amount of noise on the ASICs that I use. I contacted manufacturers who diagnosed my system using an oscilloscope and they told me that the noise very likely came from the HV power source. I use a HV power bloc connected to the rest of my electronics. They told me that the first thing to do would be to use copper braid to shield the SHV cables, like a sheath.

that really sounds like you have common mode problems; are there more than one ground connection (namely, the shield of your SHV cable) between power source and your sensitive circuits?
